# WPF Linq Results to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, data-binding, datagrid

I am trying to show my linq results using datagrid in WPF which doesnt have datasource like datagridview in winforms..

I've been struggling with this for hours now and just don't understand what it is I need to do. My code is as follows:

```
private void BindDataGrid(string searchString) //passed on button click
    {
        DatabaseEntities entity = new DatabaseEntities();

            var postcodes = (from p in entity.postcode_table
                             where p.postcode.Equals(searchString)
                             orderby p.postcode ascending
                             select p);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = postcodes;
    }
```

Any help here would be great. This isnt something I do on a day to day basis so please bear with me.

Thanks

Comment: do you have any issues with your code? can you please explain better what do you need to do?

Comment: no issues with my code. I have created a wpf form with a text box and button. When a postcode is entered and the button is clicked I need to retrieve details of the entered postcode from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Who told DataGrid doesn't have source? See below code.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataGridSource}"></DataGrid>
```

Here MyDataGridSource is the **ObservableCOllection** which contains the data. Fill it and it should work.

Comment: That hasnt worked unfortunately. When pressing the button, the grid is populated with two blank rows..